# How command prompt works in all operating system

Tags: operating-system

How command prompt communicate with hardware

1. if i give mkdir command it will create the directory
   how this command works internally
2. can i create own commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notice the difference between the OS and the shell. Shell is only a user-land program. When you type a command, the command is the name of another program(or some built-in command in shell itself), shell find the corresponding program and execute it.

The operations at this level is much higher than hardware, it's just user-land program call.

For `mkdir`, you type `which mkdir` then will find the path of this program named `mkdir`. If you want to create your own, just compile your own program and run it from shell.

Comment: shell available on linux only ? in windows shell is available?

Comment: Command prompt https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe is the windows equivalent of shell.

Answer (score 0):

First of all MKDIR doesn't change the Directory it Makes the new directory.
& These program internally runs like a Bash Script/Batch File, which are few predefined codes in the OS.

You can create your own command by creating Batch File, For which you need Notepad, Little Programing Skill & Output Parameters you Want To Achieve.

This Link Might help [Creating CMD File](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Create-your-own-Commands-with-Batch/)